# How to add data- attribute to extjs button

Tags: extjs

I want to add a data- attribute to extjs button at time of creation.I used the setAttributes method but i dont want to use setAttributes method.data- attribute should be added just like other config options.

Comment: Put your code. So we can see your effort and answer according to that

Answer (score 4):

You can use the [`autoEl`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.0.2-classic/Ext.Component.html#cfg-autoEl) property for that, like:

```
{
  xtype: 'button',
  text: 'Button',
  autoEl: {
    'data-attribute': 'foobar'
  }
}
```

Working example: https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/1d0d

Answer (score 1):

Add following code snippet in your button listeners

```
afterrender:function(button){
         button.getEl().set({
         "data-id": "some text"
         });  
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

You can add your own data attributes like this:

```
var button = new Ext.button.Button({
id: 'mybutton',
text: 'Click me',
'data-attribute': data,
handler: function() {
    alert('You clicked the button!');
}
});
```

Comment: Thank you every one for your effort. I got the solution for my issue.I tried to add attribute as said by Fresh Prince but not worked.Here is the solution i got afterrender:function(button){
button.getEl().set({
"data-intro": 'some text',
"data-step": 1
}); 
}

Comment: I updated my answer, but good to see that you got it working!

Comment: Thanks for your effort